# Stop memory monitor in Android Studio 1.2.1.1

Tags: android, android-studio, android-logcat

In Android Studio version 1.0 there was a close button beside the memory monitor panel that stops it from reporting memory changes; but in Android Studio version 1.2.1.1 the close button isn't there anymore.

The annoying thing is that `logcat` will flood the monitoring log and I can't see my log anymore.

```
05-27 16:21:24.431 32121-32127/com.exampleapp D/jdwp﹕ handlePacket : cmd=0x1, cmdSet=0xC7, len=0x14, id=0x40001396, flags=0x0, dataLen=0x9
05-27 16:21:24.431 32121-32127/com.exampleapp D/jdwp﹕ sendBufferedRequest : len=0x34     
05-27 16:21:24.932 32121-32127/com.exampleapp D/jdwp﹕ processIncoming
```

So how can i stop memory monitor and its annoying logs?

UPDATE 1:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that logs that you have listed have nothing to do with memory monitor window.

There is not much you can do about such logs. They are of "Debug" level so first thing you can do is to select a more severe log level ("Info", "Warn", "Error" or "Alert"). You can do this in the Log Level dropdown:

[image]

If you need to watch debug logs from your app then you can do

```
Log.wtf("===", "message");
```

and select Log Level "Assert". This way you'll only see your custom logs.
Or you can use a more sophisticated logging tool, like [Jake Wharton's Hugo](https://github.com/JakeWharton/hugo)

Comment: i'm sure this log is related to memory monitor, 100 percent sure, in past when i was enable memory monitor the same log appeared .  `wtf` is not a real solution but is a nice answer :)

Comment: @mehdok I have just downloaded Android Studio 1.0 and re-checked: when I set log filter to `Debug` I see jdwp messages for my application regardless of memory monitor being enabled or not. You can check it yourself: http://tools.android.com/download/studio/canary/1-0-0

Comment: you are right, i checked it again, but in previous version this kind of log was very rare, but in new version of android studio this log repeats every 2 or 3 second.

Comment: @mehdok These messages are not generated by Android Studio, but by device itself. Have you been using the same device (emulator) while testing  1.0 and 1.2.1.1?

Comment: yes they are the same devices, `Asus memo pad hd7` with android `4.2.4` and an emulator with android `5.0`

Comment: You are RIGHT, this logs created by device, i checked it again and emulator wont create this log, maybe something went wrong with my tablet, tnx alot for your help.

Answer (score 4):

creating a filter like the picture will solve the problem, but it is not a real answer also :)

[image]

Here is the filter:

```
^(?!(jdwp))
```

Answer (score 0):

> The annoying thing is that logcat will flood the monitoring log and I can't see my log anymore.

If I understand your issue correctly than here comes the easier solution. You can filter the log messages by the package name like so:
[image]

Comment: the memory log **is for current app**, so it has the `com.exampleapp` .the complete log would be some thing like this: `05-27 16:21:24.431  32121-32127/com.exampleapp D/jdwp﹕ handlePacket : cmd=0x1, cmdSet=0xC7, len=0x14, id=0x40001396, flags=0x0, dataLen=0x9
05-27 16:21:24.431  32121-32127/com.exampleapp D/jdwp﹕ sendBufferedRequest : len=0x34
05-27 16:21:24.932  32121-32127/com.exampleapp D/jdwp﹕ processIncoming`

Answer (score 0):

You can stop monitoring at anytime by disable the ADB Integration. Click on `Tools` in the top, go to `Android` and then click on `Enable ADB Integration` to deselect it. Like the following image:

[image]

To Enable `Enable ADB Integration` again you must do the same thing.

After that, you can change the `logcat` option to specify what kinda monitoring you want. In the next image shows that I wanted to monitor only logs from my app:

[image]

Comment: I disabled `ADB Integration` and no mater what filter i use, i can't see any log from my app. Am i missing something?

Comment: The `ADB Integration` is just for stopping monitoring and not to stop the logs. About your problem, maybe you are creating wrong filters. Try to create a filter using only `app: com.yourpackagename` in the `Filter Name` field, `com.yourpackagename` in the `Package Name` field and `Verbose` selected in the `Log Level`. Let empty in the rest of the fields.×Comments may only be edited for 5 minutes×Comments may only be edited for 5 minutes×Comments may only be edited for 5 minutes.

Comment: Doing so, you will see the logs from your app. However, if you wanna see a specific log, you must use the search field beside the filters like another guy has said in a previously answer.

Comment: So please, take a print screen of it

Comment: That is apparently right. I did some testes here and I think you have to enable `ADB Integration` so that you will see your logs